# Kotlin: file-level private functions generate a new public class

Tags: kotlin

I am migrating a Java codebase to Kotlin, and I have a Java class with the following quite common structure:

```java
class A {
    // public static factories
    // private constructors
    // public A methods
    // private A methods
    // private static helpers
}
```

My problem is what to do with the *private static* helpers.

In Kotlin, if I put them as file-level private functions:

```
class A private constructor(...) {
    companion object {
        // factories
    }
    // A methods
    // private A methods
}

// private helpers
```

Then when using the code from Java there will be a new `AKt` class in the package, with no methods but still visible (and appearing as suggestion in the IDE). What was nicely isolated before now "leaks" as a new unintended public class into the API.

Having the private static helpers in the companion object is not really the same, because now the "logical" organization of the class is all "backwards" with the private, unimportant helpers being at the top:

```
class A private constructor(...) {
    companion object {
        // factories
        // private helpers
    }
    // A methods
    // private A methods
}
```

Is there a better alternative? Some way to hide the `AKt` generated class maybe?

---

**Edit:** I though that the `AKt` class had a public constructor because IntelliJ doesn't mark this as an error when editing the file:

```java
AKt a = new AKt();
```

Not in the same project, and not in a client.

But when building the project, or when compiled with Gradle, it does fails with:

```
error: cannot find symbol
AKt mk = new AKt();
```

Comment: You can also define private helpers as actual *local* functions, defining them within another function, if they're only used in one place.  Or just stop treating them as static, and let them be instance functions!

Answer (score 1):

Make it an `internal` class. It will no longer be visible in the public API.

Comment: But what I want to hide is the `AKt` class generated from the top-level private functions. The `A` class is supposed to be public.

Comment: Also, it won't be visible from Kotlin, but Java doesn't know about `internal`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, put them in a non-companion object:

```
// optional to make the methods available without `Helpers.`
import A.Helpers.*

class A private constructor(...) {
    companion object {
        // factories
    }
    // A methods
    // private A methods
    private object Helpers {
        // private helpers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JvmSynthetic` annotation. This is what docs says:

> Sets `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag on the annotated target in the Java
>   bytecode.
>
> Synthetic targets become inaccessible for Java sources at compile time
>   while still being accessible for Kotlin sources. Marking target as
>   synthetic is a binary compatible change, already compiled Java code
>   will be able to access such target.
>
> This annotation is intended for *rare cases* when API designer needs
>   to hide Kotlin-specific target from Java API
>
> while keeping it a part of Kotlin API so the resulting API is
>   idiomatic for both languages.